What does "the heathen" have to do with "horseback riding" here?
In I Am Homeless if This Is Not My Home by Lorrie Moore, Eliz narrates a conversation between her and Jack:

“God has gone horseback riding,” I say, “and we are left behind to
tend to one another.”
“Well aren’t you the heathen.” He smiled.
“I don’t care much for horseback riding.”
“Too much hucklebuck?”
That sort of remark is when I try to find something else I must do.
Pies to make and curtains to mend.

Before this Jack had made some racialistic remarks against the housekeeper, Ofelia, and Eliz stood up for her. I can't understand the flow of this dialogue. What does it mean?

I don't know the book, but my presumption is that this is simply reflecting the original comment. God would not literally go horseback riding, so that claim makes Eliz sound like a heathen. Plus, if God has indeed "gone" then they're both heathens, in a sense.

I wonder whether it's a reference to Elijah's taunting the worshippers of Baal in 1 Kings 18:27? When Baal doesn't answer their prayers, Elijah suggests other things he might be doing such as sleeping or being away on a journey.

@MattThrower An alternative take: if God likes horseback riding but she doesn't, that would make her far from God and therefore a heathen?

Jack is a lodger in a boarding house, and is frequently shown to be a show-off. He dresses flamboyantly, recites poetry and passages from plays, and generally tries to call attention to himself. In keeping with his character he also flirts with the women around: namely Eliz, the owner of the boarding house, who notes how he seems "keen to relieve her of her spinsterhood", and also with the black housekeeper, Ofelia (although this seems less serious). Accordingly this passage has a bantering tone between the participants.
This part of the novel is set shortly after the American Civil War, and Jack is implied to be a secessionist ("a secesher"), on the side of the South. The dialogue opens with Jack asking Eliz if Ofelia ever stayed at the boarding house overnight.

I tell him I sometimes allow it, if it's more convenient for her.
"There's no cause for unkindness."
"She's under the same roof. God has made distinctions among us!"

i.e. he believes that black and white people should not be present in the same house at night.
Hearing him reveal his racism openly makes Eliz begin to despise him, and she retorts "God has gone horseback riding", that is, God has abandoned us* to go and do other things, leaving it up to we humans ourselves "to tend to one another". As noted in a comment, this resembles Elijah mocking the priests of Baal, asking if he was "away on a journey, or perhaps he is sleeping". We have already learned earlier that although she seems quite a prim and proper member of the community, Eliz actually has little respect for religion in general (and for the local pastor in particular).
Presumably not realizing the degree to which he has offended her, Jack playfully responds, "Well aren't you the heathen" - trying to tease her by commenting that God is not present anymore in the world would be a very non-Christian thing to say. Eliz retakes the metaphor and replies "I don't care for horseback riding", confirming that she was not interested in "God said so"-type arguments. Jack attempts a final piece of humor which again falls flat, asking "Too much hucklebuck?". This is many decades too early for this to be a reference to the dance of this name, but rather a reference to the bouncing motion a person experiences when riding a horse, probably with an insinuation of how women are said to get a feeling of sexual gratification from it. At this point Eliz breaks the conversation off to go and do some useful work.
 * Similar in feeling to the line in Praying for Time by George Michael, "God's stopped keeping score" 
